# DoInBackground doesn't work second time

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a synchronism logic makes sendOrder from db in android to server by web service which runs on `doInBackgroud()`.

first I start app.
then click `SyncClick` and It Sync database without error.
after that I go into application add someorder to orderTable
return to main screen(which has SyncClick) and I click SyncClick again.
It sends order (which means `sendOrder()` function works well) 
after that reset database and get latest data on `doInBackgroud()`.
but It getting this error;

```
07-11 23:38:15.406: E/AndroidRuntime(7864): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

07-11 23:38:15.406: E/AndroidRuntime(7864): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

after I start app and click SyncClick works well again. so It doesn't work after I add some order then Sync but works well without any order added.

looking for problem.
thanks for your time in advance.

```
public void SyncClick(View v) 
    {
        Loading = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgLoadingAnim);
        LoadingLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.loLoadingAnim);
        LoadingLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        Loading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loading);
        frameAnimation= (AnimationDrawable)Loading.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.setCallback(Loading);
        frameAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
        frameAnimation.start();

        if(!this.dhn.isTableExists("Orders"))
        {
            updateDB();
        }

        sendOrder();    
    }


    public void sendOrder()
    {
        ArrayList<Object[]> argumentsList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        Object[] stuff = {this.dhn, this};
        //SEND
        ArrayList<Order> orders = this.dhn.GetOrders();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < orders.size(); i++)
        {
            ArrayList<OrderItem> orderItems = this.dhn.GetOrderItems(orders.get(i).ID);

            String orderItemsS = "";

            for(int r = 0 ; r < orderItems.size(); r++)
            {
                orderItemsS = orderItemsS + orderItems.get(r).FinalCode + "|" + orderItems.get(r).Quantity + "|" +
                orderItems.get(r).Price + "|" + orderItems.get(r).Discount + "|" + orderItems.get(r).Status + "|" + "#";
            }

            orderItemsS = orderItemsS.substring(0, orderItemsS.length() - 1);

            Object[] arguments = { 
                    new String("OrderAdd"), 
                    stuff,

                    new String("UserId"),
                    new Integer (orders.get(i).UserId),
                    new String("int"),

                    new String("CustomerId"),
                    new Integer (orders.get(i).CustomerId),
                    new String("int"),

                    new String("Price"),
                    new Double (orders.get(i).Price),
                    new String("double"),

                    new String("Discount"),
                    new Double (orders.get(i).Discount),
                    new String("double"),

                    new String("Status"),
                    new Integer (orders.get(i).Status),
                    new String("int"),

                    new String("orderItems"),
                    new String (orderItemsS),
                    new String("String")
                    };

            argumentsList.add(arguments);
        }

        Object[] stuffALL = {this.dhn, this, argumentsList};


        Object[] argumentsALL = { 
                new String("recieveALL"), 
                stuffALL
                };

        //ConnectXML runXMLALL = new ConnectXML();
        new ConnectXML().execute(argumentsALL);


        Status = 1;

        updateDB();

        receive();
    }

    public void receive()
    {
        Object[] stuff = {this.dhn, this};
        ArrayList<Object[]> argumentsList1 = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        //receive
        Object[] arguments = { 
                new String("ProductListGet"), 
                stuff,
                new String("CatID"),
                new Integer (-1),
                new String("int")
                };
        argumentsList1.add(arguments);
        Object[] arguments1 = { 
                new String("CustomerListGet"), 
                stuff
                };
        argumentsList1.add(arguments1);
        Object[] arguments2 = { 
                new String("CategoryListGet"), 
                stuff,
                new String("ParentID"),
                new Integer (-2),
                new String("int")
                };
        argumentsList1.add(arguments2);
        Object[] arguments3 = { 
                new String("UserListGet"), 
                stuff
                };
        argumentsList1.add(arguments3);
        Object[] arguments5 = { 
                new String("ProductCategoriesListGet"), 
                stuff
                };
        argumentsList1.add(arguments5);
        Object[] arguments6 = { 
                new String("ProductOptionListGet"), 
                stuff
                };
        argumentsList1.add(arguments6);
        Object[] arguments7 = { 
                new String("FinalProductListGet"), 
                stuff
                };
        argumentsList1.add(arguments7);
        Object[] arguments8 = { 
                new String("ProductDiscountsListGet"), 
                stuff
                };
        argumentsList1.add(arguments8);
        Object[] arguments9 = { 
                new String("ProductPriceGroupListGet"), 
                stuff
                };
        argumentsList1.add(arguments9);
        Object[] arguments10 = { 
                new String("OptionListGet"), 
                stuff
                };
        argumentsList1.add(arguments10);


        Object[] stuffALL1 = {this.dhn, this, argumentsList1};


        Object[] argumentsALL1 = { 
                new String("recieveALL"), 
                stuffALL1
                };

        //ConnectXML runXMLALL1 = new ConnectXML();
        new ConnectXML().execute(argumentsALL1);
    }

    int Stat;
    int Status;
    public void LoadAnim()
    {   
        if(Status == 1)
        {
            Stat++;
            if(Stat > 0)
            {
                LoadingLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                if(frameAnimation !=null && frameAnimation.isRunning())
                { 
                    frameAnimation.stop();
                    Stat = 0;
                    Status = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateDB()
    {
        this.dhn.close();

        try {
            InputStream myInput;

                myInput = getAssets().open("sistem.db");

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = "/data/data/sistem.ss/databases/"
                    + "sistem.db";

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
            buffer = null;
            outFileName = null;
            this.dhn.close();
            this.dhn = null;
            this.dhn = DataHelper.getDataHelper(this);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

LogCat

```
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     at sistem.ss.ConnectXML.doInBackground(ConnectXML.java:79)
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     at sistem.ss.ConnectXML.doInBackground(ConnectXML.java:1)
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-12 07:31:59.879: E/AndroidRuntime(2873):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Can you post the whole LogCat output? Just "`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`" is not really enough to go on. There should be some line that points to a line in your code where the null pointer is occurring.

Comment: Have you considered using an AsycTask for this?

Comment: @Blaine Anderson what do you mean DoInBackgroud() is AsycTask, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't yet had a chance to work with AsyncTask, but the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) says:

> The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

That means you just need to create a new instance and execute on that one. E.g.

```
new WhateverYourTaskIsCalled().execute(...);
```

Rather than calling `execute()` on the instance you've already used.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I just edit my code a bit as your suggestion on the top in question. but still gives me java.lang.NullPointerException.. I have breakpoint starting of doInBackground() It jumps on breakpoint and works look fine but still crush because of exception.. Also tried create a public task and use second time but It says "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running." thanks for your time waiting yours

Comment: @Mert It sounds like you were already using a new instance as is appropriate, but you have some other error in your code.  Look at the exact line causing the `NullPointerException` and try to figure out what assumption you're making that isn't true (something on that line is `null`, and you're assuming it shouldn't be.)  If you can't figure it out, you'll need to post the relevant code (the line and surrounding context of where you're getting the Exception).

Comment: I found the problem in doInBackground().. It was a silly one. took you guys time. sorry for that. I appreciate you time so I accept your answer for your effort. thanks again.