# crash with doInBackGround call json more than time

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        //getting JSON string from URL
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 11 ; i++){

            jsonFiles[i] = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(webServiceMethods[i]);
        }
        for(int ii = 0 ; ii < jsonFiles.length ; ii++){
            System.out.println(jsonFiles[ii]);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I call json only one time, it's work fine but when I use looping I got Future task exception, what can be done to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add the LogCat error please.

Comment: -- java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

-- at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)

--  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 

*** alot of error

Comment: Look out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442920/doinbackground-doesnt-work-second-time?rq=1